# Java httpclient 4.1 how to send post request with configurable port

Tags: java, https, httpclient

wow , i just can't find any working httpclient 4.1 example , to send post request with Not default port 
but configurable port , i have this code but its dosn't work

```
// lHashMapParams is with params getting form function .. 

List<BasicNameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
        for (String key : lHashMapParams.keySet()) {
            String val = lHashMapParams.get(key);
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key,val));

}
String url = "https://foo.com";
int port = 8883;
String = "https";
UrlEncodedFormEntity query = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params);
        HttpHost httpHost = new HttpHost(url,port,httpType); 

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("/");
        post.setEntity(query);


        HttpResponse response_ = httpclient.execute(httpHost,post);
```

getting this exception :

```
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
java.net.UnknownHostException: https://foo.com
    at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:849)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1183)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1136)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1109)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1072)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:242)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:130)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:561)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:776)
    at com.ut.HttpClientImpl.postHttpReqest(HttpClientImpl.java:75)
```

is simple words how to define port ?

Comment: That code says "unknown host" and nothing about the port. The port is the part of the URL. `http://foo.com:8888` will try to connect to `foo.com` on port `8888`.

Comment: i know its like it dosn't know the port even so i did put value in the 
new HttpHost(url,port,httpType);

Comment: That's not the point, though - the host is not found in DNS, the port is not relevant.

Comment: when i excute the code in this form :
http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient
every thing is working fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attempting to perform a lookup of the host name `https://foo.com`
 and that's the problem; the lookup should have been against `foo.com`. I'm not sure as to how you've arrived at the code in question, but it would be worth some time to take a look at the [HttpClient tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/index.html).

If I'm not wrong, the following code, should be sufficient:

```
HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(url); //construct the complete URL i.e. action to post to
httpost.setEntity(entity);
response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
```

where url is to be constructed with the http/https schema, host name, port and the rest of the resource URI.

Comment: Yes, take a look at the example for form-based login at the examples page for [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html).

Comment: i saw all of them this is way i asked the question , way there isn't some method to set port like C cUrl , why i need to build the string its stupid

Comment: Maybe you should spend more time on the tutorial. Chapter 1 shows how to accomplish this using [URIUtils](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d4e43).

Comment: not good i still need to build the query , way not use some kind of vector of per's

Comment: If you're using POST, why do you need to build the query string? Why not use the POST Body, which happens to the HTTP Entity that you're apparently referring to? I think you need to understand the purpose of the classes in HttpClient before you proceed with programming against it. Understanding the object model of HttpClient and mapping it to the HTTP protocol goes a long way in ensuring that you will be able to accomplish any aspect of the HTTP protocol that HttpClient supports.